# Multiple Update with Multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql, update

We are told to watch out for things being set to null (we dont want) by using the IN clause in the following:

```
UPDATE Tests SET
     TestScore =
              CASE
                  WHEN TestId = 10 THEN 1000
                  WHEN TestId = 11 THEN 1100
              END,
     TestScore2 =
              CASE
                  WHEN TestId = 10 THEN 2000
                  WHEN TestId = 11 THEN 2100
              END
     WHERE TestId IN (10, 11)
```

But what happens when there two conditions required, namely the joint combo of (TestId, TestSubId)? Ie, what do I do for the IN clause, the ???, in the following to show it has to be in the combos (10,25) and (11,22):

```
UPDATE Tests SET
    TestScore = CASE
        WHEN (TestId = 10 AND TestSubId = 25) THEN 1000
        WHEN (TestId = 11 AND TestSubId = 22) THEN 1100
    END,
    TestScore2 = CASE
        WHEN (TestId = 10 AND TestSubId = 25) THEN 2000
        WHEN (TestId = 11 AND TestSubId = 22) THEN 2100
    END
    WHERE TestId, TestSubId IN ?????
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use tuple comparison:

```
WHERE (TestId, TestSubId) IN ((10,25), (11,22))
```

That looks nice and succinct, although, as [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) mentioned in a comment, it may not work well performance-wise.

However, given how the conditions are re-used in your UPDATE statement, you could also take a different approach altogether: represent the affected IDs and the new values as a derived table and use an update with a join:

```
UPDATE
    Tests AS old
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 10 AS TestId, 25 AS TestSubId, 1000 AS TestScore, 2000 AS TestScore2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 11, 22, 1100, 2100
    ) AS new
    ON old.TestId = new.TestId AND old.TestSubId = new.TestSubId
SET
    old.TestScore  = new.TestScore,
    old.TestScore2 = new.TestScore2
;
```

This way the `new` derived table acts both as a filter for `Tests` and a supplier of new values for the update.

Comment: This looks really classy. Should I use this method to replace the standard case (my first blue bit of code in my OP) where I use the 'IN (10, 11)'.

Comment: @Rewind: I've certainly used this in SQL Server. It's somewhat inconvenient that MySQL doesn't let you supply column aliases after the table alias, for derived tables, as in `... FROM (SELECT 10, 25, 1000, 2000 UNION ALL SELECT 11, 22, 1100, 2100) AS new (TestId, TestSubId, TestScore, TestScore2)` – IMHO, that would have made the query look a little more elegant. Nevertheless, I would still use the technique despite that limitation.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the `in` operator to filter two different columns.  For this example, you would have to use the standard logical operators:

```
UPDATE Tests SET
TestScore = CASE
    WHEN (TestId = 10 AND TestSubId = 25) THEN 1000
    WHEN (TestId = 11 AND TestSubId = 22) THEN 1100
END,
TestScore2 = CASE
    WHEN (TestId = 10 AND TestSubId = 25) THEN 2000
    WHEN (TestId = 11 AND TestSubId = 22) THEN 2100
END
WHERE (TestId = 10 AND TestSubId = 25)
  OR (TestId = 11 AND TestSubId = 22)
```